# error: Cannot load module 'webkit' as 'WebKit'

Tags: swift, ios8, webkit

[image]

I had just created a new project for working with `WebKit`,but when I just create a project and write as ,

```
import WebKit  // error:Cannot load module 'webkit' as 'WebKit'
```

Compiler throws an error

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: swift complier error: Cannot load module 'webkit' as 'WebKit'

Comment: What version of Xcode and Swift are you using?

Comment: xcode 6.4,  For clear view I had added a snap shot to my question

Answer (score 4):

Isn't your project name 'webkit'? If it is so, the compiler misinterprets the framework name with your target name.